# AngularJs: Taking parameter from current route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a site using AngularJs and I couldn't find a way to take a parameter from the site name of the current page I am at this moment. To explain better, I have the following HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="attendantsController">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="{{student.id}}" class="col-sm-4 col-md-3" ng-repeat="student in vm.students">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{student.user_id}}</h3>
                <p>{{student.faculty}}</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="/#!/internships/?/attendants/{{student.id}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">More Info</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now this page is displayed on the following browser link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/#!/internships/4/attendants/
```

What I want to do is to take the 4 from the /internships/4/attendants/ and add it where the ? is in my code. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: you should use ui-router which simplyfies and enhances the default router

Comment: i know this does not really help you but it seems like you have just started to build the site, thus i strongly recommend you to use Angular 4 / 5 - https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: Which router are you using? Show your routing config